# Ad Hoc queries on Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hive, apache-pig

We are processing 24 million businesses in the US.  We are now using Pig on HDFS an Hadoop.  We hope to speed up the ad hoc query for debugging.  E.g. right now it takes a few minutes to grep one business out of the 24 million business out of our 5 severs cluster.

Hbase seems the only system I found that can do the job.  Hive doesn't seem to do it.

Here is our schema currently stored as tab delimited flat text file in HDFS.

```
place_id name value
1  Title    Bamboo Garden
1  Title    Bamboo Garden Restaurant
1  Phone 425-555-555
1  Phone 425-444-444
1  Address 123 Bellevue Way
2  Title    Burger King
2  Phone 425-333-3333
```

We choose this name value pair for the flexibility of assembling addition data and fields.  E.g. if we want to union two data set, we can easily "cat" them.  Also It's very easy to add more new fields.  This schema is designed long time ago and there is very little chance to change it.

We find it very hard to model this in Hbase, as Hbase doesn't support duplicate keys.  As you can see in the above example, each business can have multiple phone numbers, titles, comments etc.

So my questions

1. What are the ideas to speed up ad hoc queries like this in
   Hadoop?
2. What's the best practice to store array of strings in
   HBase?
3. How to model this key value pairs with duplicate keys in
   HBase?

**Edited after reading questions in comments:**
Most common **ad hoc query** is to return all info of a business with a given id.  There are other nice to have ad hoc queries support such as return a business given zip code and title.

Suggestion in the comments of using RDBMS to support ad hoc query is a good one.  But I was hoping to have one system to support both streaming and ad hoc queries.  Our ad hoc queries are required mainly for debugging.  If we find a bug in our data, we still need to verify if it's a bug in our Hadoop data so querying RDBMS won't be enough.

Most common **streaming processing query** is to join two large data set and match the businesses among the two data set.  There are much more streaming processing query support requirements than ad hoc query thus we choose Hadoop.  Our ad hoc queries are mostly for debugging.

Comment: I'm a little unclear on why you aren't just using an ordinary SQL database for this.  Such databases can easily handle 24 million records without much effort, and you can do very sophisticated searches with them.  I realize that NoSql is all the range but *[Will Smith voice]* daaammn.

Comment: What do your queries look like? That will determine what your HBase schema/keys should be structured.

Comment: Shark might be of some interest to you: http://shark.cs.berkeley.edu/

Answer (score 2):

**What are the ideas to speed up ad hoc queries like this in Hadoop?**

I don't think you should try. Hadoop is for batch analysis, not record fetching.

---

**What's the best practice to store array of strings in HBase?**

There are a couple of ways to do this. If you don't have many updates, store the string array in one string in a serialized fashion. Something like `425-555-5555^425-444-444` in a cell called "phone". In Pig and Hive, you can use some simple string splitting utilities to convert this back into an array.

If you add numbers frequently, then you could have the cells called `"phone1"`, `"phone[2]"`, etc. This makes processing with Pig and Hive pretty hard.

---

**How to model this key value pairs with duplicate keys in HBase?**

Basically, what you have implemented in the SQL schema is a doubly nested map, which is exactly what HBase is. So modeling the data should be pretty easy.

You dot need to duplicate the keys here. Have the title of the business be the key since that seems to be singular. You do want to figure out a way to make it unique, though, since I suppose "Burger King" might exist in more than one place. One thing I would suggest is having the name of the business be part of the key, but add something that makes it unique.

Example: `"Bambo Garden^1"`, `"Burger King^2"` or `"Bamboo Garden^123 Bellvue Way"`.

Under these keys, have the phone numbers, addresses, and whatever else.

You can still add columns like you were before as you aren't ever specifying schema anymore. All your old code will still work and will just ignore new columns as they come up.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas.  array of strings in HBase appears a bit ugly.  We can use place_id as the unique key.  My questions is how to store multiple phones, titles, comments etc.  That would go back to question 2 whose solutions you proposed are either query-unfriendly or update-unfriendly.  But thanks for the ideas anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Pig/Hive are used primarily for batch processing and not for real time adhoc querying..

[Apache Drill](http://incubator.apache.org/projects/drill.html) has been kicked, which is an implementation of [Google Dremel](http://research.google.com/pubs/pub36632.html) for interactive adhoc query. It might be some time before something solid materializes out of Apache Drill. Till then you can use [Google BigQuery](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/) cloud service which is used to interactively analyze massive datasets — up to billions of rows.

One of the goal of Apache Drill is to use it in conjunction with data sources like HBase and HDFS. So, it should be possible to use Apache Drill as a query engine with data in HDFS.

Comment: Please don't past duplicate answers. If the question is a duplicate, flag or close it as such. If not, then please tailor your answer to the specific question asked.

Comment: Two different questions might have a same answer. I don't see a problem with it.

Comment: Besides being spammy, neither question has asked for the answer you provided. You mention Hadoop *no where* in your answer. In any other case, I'd consider this answer spam and just delete it.  I'm letting you know so that in the future, you won't post a duplicate answer to multiple questions.

Comment: Sorry to say !!! Moderations like these without any proper reasoning discourage users to participate. You might delete it since you have the permissions, but I again want to iterate that there might be same answer for two different queries. Both the queries are not same, what would I be marking as duplicate. This is not the first time I am posting on Hadoop. I had been the user with the top score for the Hadoop, HDFS and the MapReduce tags. Also, I think it's more to the users who are authoritative about Hadoop to decide if the response is spammy or not.

Answer (score 0):

As Robert mentioned in a comment you're best bet is probably a regular RDBMS.

Regarding ad-hoc queries and ways to store an array- what queries are you looking to do (this greatly affects how you model things in HBase).

Regarding your 3rd question. The simplest way to store this (which might not be the best as I mentioned above) is to make the "name" into a qualifier (a "column"). If you have multiple values (e.g. phone numbers) you can just have multiple qualifiers (assuming column family is f you'd have f:phone1,f:phone2..) and you'd be able to fetch columns by prefix (all columns starting with phone)

Arnon

Comment: See my updated for the answers to your questions.  It appears non trivial to convert to hbase as we have hundred of column names.

Comment: It is trivial as HBase columns are created the first time you write them (you don't predefine the schema only the table and column families)

Comment: What about using AVRO, serialize it binary and save it as a column, thus avoiding duplicity.

Comment: The problem with AVRO is that you have to retrieve all the data and only filter later so ad-hoc queries can be more problematic. You can overcome that by using co-processors (there is a project by intel that does that https://github.com/intel-hadoop/project-panthera-dot) but I think they made some changes to hbase to make it work